# Send email to Marucry XAMPP localhost from Outlook 2007

Tags: outlook, xampp, localhost, mercury-mta

I am trying to setup email in XAMPP with Mercury mail. However I have done all part and configured in outlook 2007.

But when I am trying to send email from localhost email id to other localhost email id, outlook not sending by saying Outlook does not recognize newuser@localhost

So how to send email to localhost account through outlook 2007?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four domains in MERCURY.INI file:

- localhost
- localhost.com
- localhost.org
- localhost.net

Three last are acceptable to Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried Denis' answer.

> There are four domains in MERCURY.INI file:
>
> ```
> localhost
> localhost.com
> localhost.org
> localhost.net
> ```
>
> Three last are acceptable to Outlook.

It works well. You can also add in custom domains as well for training environments